# Updating ASP.Net Core Angular template from Version 8 to 9

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

The book that i read has version 9 from the beginning (ASP.NET Core 3 and Angular 9 - Third Edition) and uses also the angular template. I have the latest visual studio updates for vs 2019 installed.

The template of a Angular project has version 8. The book I read is with version 9. So i try to update my angular version.
`ng update` gives me

```
@angular/cli 8.3.14 -> 9.0.3 ng update @angular/cli

@angular/core 8.2.12 -> 9.0.3 ng update @angular/core

@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine 8.1.1 -> 8.2.6 ng update @nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine
```

I updated cli and core. But when I try to update the third package I get:

```
C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp>ng update @nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 39 dependencies.
Package '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine' is not a dependency.
```

I tried to run the application anyway and I get as HTML

```
Cannot GET /
```

Or a exception page with:

```
System.TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: try -> dotnet run   l then navigate to localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little late but maybe this helps others. I faced the exact same problem.
To make it work do this in the package.json.

Change

```json
"scripts":{
   ...
   "start": "ng serve"
   ...
}
```

```json
"scripts":{
   ...
   "start": "echo Starting... && ng serve"
   ...
}
```

> This was taken from a comment by [Smatusan](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16961#issuecomment-612086051). This is the [explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16961#issuecomment-678695094) of why it works.

"Because this problem frequently occurs due to the initial build time of ng serve exceeding the programmed timeout window of the .NET SPA service, so by giving it the echo, the .NET SPA service receives some data and believes it's connected." - [mikejunt](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16961#issuecomment-678695094).

The complete issue on GitHub can be found on the [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16961) side and the [.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17277) side

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded my angular version to 11 and was still running .net core 3.1.

How I solved it:

Completed Angular updates (ensure node modules are all up to date as well)
Installed .Net core 5.0
Right click solution->properties->Application: Target Framework dropdown (change to recently installed 5.0)
Save changes
Manage Nuget packages
-> Update Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions to version 5+

Then i was able to launch my debug sessions as normal.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading Angular from v8 to v9 'ng update' adds this line in main.ts

```
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Just remove it, and the above error is gone, check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896)